# Azure powershell - application id and client secret login problem

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-automation

I try to use my application ID and client secret token to login in PowerShell. But I got the error message in following content. What should I do to mke it have enough permission?

My script:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "client secret" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "application ID", $password

Write-Output "Login to azure environment"

Connect-AzAccount -Credential $cred -Tenant "tenant ID" -Subscription "subscription ID" -ServicePrincipal

Write-Output "Restarting Web App..."

Restart-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "testconfogproxy_group" -Name "testconfogproxy"

Write-Output "Operation Completed."
```

Error message.

```
Connect-AzAccount : The provided account adf74536-2bd3-456a-96ba-2f98e4902525 does not have access to subscription ID "
d9c408ef-39c7-408a-97c7-68c6ae84b760". Please try logging in with different credentials or a different subscription ID.
 If a subscription is not specified, please check the configs by `Get-AzConfig`.
```

Comment: In order to resolve the error, ***Make sure your Service Principal has atleast Contributor or Owner role assigned at the subscription level or to the Web app or Resource Group*** containing Web app, Refer here:-***My service principal having Owner role at the subscription level:-***  https://i.imgur.com/W7ikpwy.png . After assigning the role, I ran the command to Restart my Web app and it ran successfully, Refer below:- https://i.imgur.com/4Q3WKW1.png,  https://i.imgur.com/R4roOwG.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the service principal has the proper `contributor` role under both the automation account and the web app.

Also, go to the corresponding paths to see if you enabled `system managed identity` for the automation account and provided automation `contributor` role for the related service principal.

`Automation account >> Access control >> Add a role assignment` and follow the same for web app at the subscription role.

If still the issue persists, assign the appropriate `Contributor or Owner` role to the service principal associated with the application ID.

[image]

After providing the necessary permissions, I was able to execute the below script successfully as shown.

```
$clientsecret="xxx"
$appid="xxxx"
$tenantid="xxxx"
$subscriptionid="xxxx"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientsecret -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $appid, $password
Write-Output "Login to azure environment"
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantid -Subscription $subscriptionid -ServicePrincipal
Write-Output "Restarting Web App..."
Restart-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -Name "newapj"
Write-Output "Operation Completed."
```

***Output:***

[image]

And I also tried running the script from Azure PowerShell. Here to login and restart the web app from PowerShell, you need to provide `website contributor`   role as well to the application Id for accessing it with the service principal.

*Goto below path:*

`Webapp >> Access control >> Add a role assignment >> website contributor >> select your service principal app id`

[image]